# Nonetype object not callable error on pandas datarame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

wrote a program to create a dataframe from a csv file and use it to scrap data from websites. Keep getting error with calling functions on the dataframe.

```
import pandas
import requests
from bsf import BeautifulSoup
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/Sheet1.csv", 
encoding= "utf-8")
res=requests.get(data.iloc[0,1])
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
page_title=soup.title.text
content= soup.find_all("div", {"class":["tdb-block-wrap", 
"tdb_single_content"]})
f=open(f"C:/Users/PC/OneDrive/Desktop/web_scrap/{data.iloc[0,0]}.txt", "w")

f.writelines(page_title)
for data in content:
  f.writelines(data.text)
  print(data.text)
  f.close()

print(f"web scraping for file {data.iloc[0,0]} done")

data.drop(0, axis=0)
```

It works fine initially but keeps giving the NoneType Obect Error at the end.

```
----------------------------------- 
----------------------------------- 
-----
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 4
      1 import requests
      2 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
----> 4 
res=requests.get(data.iloc[0,1])
      5 soup=BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
      6 page_title=soup.title.text

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

some lines of the csv file are-

```
data.head()

    URL_ID  URL
       0    37.0    https://insights.blackcoffer.com/ai-in-healthc...
       1    38.0    https://insights.blackcoffer.com/what-if-the-c...
       2    39.0    https://insights.blackcoffer.com/what-jobs-wil...
       3    40.0    https://insights.blackcoffer.com/will-machine-...
       4    41.0    https://insights.blackcoffer.com/will-ai-repla...
```

Comment: Please [edit] your indentation and include the full error traceback, as that contains important information to allow us to know how to help. The error is telling you that one of your variables is `None`, but there's no way for us to know which one or why

Comment: Just added the full traceback, any help would be appreciated

Comment: please add some lines of the csv file

Comment: added some lines of the csv file as well